# Why HTML/CSS Dropdown Menu links not clicking thru on 1st click, only 2nd+ click works?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, click

Strangely, all of the links in a HTML/CSS/JS dropdown menu (top right with parent menu items "Home" "Shop" "Create" as shown in example image), do not click-thru to their href= destinations on the 1st click.  Clicking 1 time does nothing.  Wait a few seconds to verify nothing happens, then click again - works browser follows the link to the destination on the 2nd click fine.

I am testing in Google Chrome.

This is the only menu or set of links having this issue in the entire site...

I've already right-clicked on them to inspect-element with the developer panel in Chrome, expecting to find some other element blocking it or something but it's not the case, the target seems clickable and the hover states work fine and everything.

View example here:  http://www.PuckStyle.com

Thank you!

**Update:**

Here is a screenshot as requested-

[image]
<sub>(source: [puckstyle.com](https://puckstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/screenshot-dropdown-link-not-working-on-first-click-in-google-chrome.png))</sub>

Comment: It is working, tested in chrome! Can we have screenshot of which link is not working for you?

Comment: @Chiru I've added the screenshot as requested.

Comment: I have verified this on 3 different computers with Google Chrome.

Comment: @OGSean All links are working from first time on Chrome

Comment: I dont know, but maybe you have some Chrome extension that is making this happen? It seems to be working fine for everyone else...

Comment: @OGSean I confirm it is behaving like you describe in my Chrome browser even when I turn Private navigation ON. Not sure how to find what's causing this.

Comment: Is this question still open? It works for me

Comment: Question is now answered / bounty granted.  The theme had a doubleclick behavior built in for touch enabled devices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to find something using the Chrome dev tools checking for events.

If I remove that click event (1) then I can single click the link in the menu.

[image]

When I click the link to the script (2), the code block (3) is highlighted.

[image]

Looks like a script to double-tap. You could remove it from your site. Double-taping in your website is probably not needed.

Comment: Thank you, I think you found it.  It's part of the "mystile them" and another article references the same unwanted behavior although no solution was provided, here's the link:   https://wordpress.org/support/topic/mystile-theme-users-have-to-double-tap-to-access-menu-item-on-mobile-devices/